# Azure Storage Emulator - Configuring CORS dynamically throws Server Authentication error

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-storage

I'm using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage C# library in .Net Core 2.0.
Using this library I'm trying to configure CORS dynamically in Azure Storage Emulator but getting error:

> "Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature".

```
public async void ConfigureCors() {
        ServiceProperties serviceProperties = await this.blobClient.GetServicePropertiesAsync();

        serviceProperties.Cors = new CorsProperties();
        serviceProperties.Cors.CorsRules.Clear();
        serviceProperties.Cors.CorsRules.Add(new CorsRule() {
            AllowedHeaders = allowedCorsHeaders,
            ExposedHeaders = allowedCorsExposedHeaders,
            AllowedOrigins = allowedCorsOrigin,
            AllowedMethods = allowedCorsMethods,
            MaxAgeInSeconds = allowedCorsAgeInSeconds
        });
        await blobClient.SetServicePropertiesAsync(serviceProperties);
    }
```

I'm able to generate SAS key for upload files on local server directly, but is not able to configure CORS dynamically so that I can access storage via C# code.

**Strange thing to note is that the above code is working perfectly fine when using Azure Storage Cloud but local emulator is throwing this error.**

**Version info:**

WindowsAzure.Storage version is 8.4.0

Windows Azure Storage Emulator version 5.2.0.0

Azure storage explorer version is 0.9.01

**Credentials used for connection:**

AccountName=devstoreaccount1;

AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuF‌​q2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFP‌​TOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I have created a test demo on my side. It works well.

I guess the reason why you get the `Server failed to authenticate the request` error is the wrong azure storage package version and storage emulator version.

I suggest you could update the storage version to 8.4.0 and storage emulator version to 5.2 firstly and try again.

More details about my test demo, you could refer to below codes:

```
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");

        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();



        ServiceProperties serviceProperties = blobClient.GetServicePropertiesAsync().Result;

        serviceProperties.Cors = new CorsProperties();
        serviceProperties.Cors.CorsRules.Clear();
        serviceProperties.Cors.CorsRules.Add(new CorsRule()
        {
            AllowedHeaders = new List<string>() { "*" },
            ExposedHeaders = new List<string>() { "*" },
            AllowedOrigins = new List<string>() { "*" },
            AllowedMethods = CorsHttpMethods.Put | CorsHttpMethods.Get | CorsHttpMethods.Head | CorsHttpMethods.Post,
            MaxAgeInSeconds = 1800
        });
       var re =  blobClient.SetServicePropertiesAsync(serviceProperties);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: WindowsAzure.Storage version is 8.4.0
Windows Azure Storage Emulator version 5.2.0.0
and Azure storage explorer version is 0.9.01

Comment: Credentials used for connection: AccountName=devstoreaccount1;
AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;